# To find the equation in polar co-ordinates of a circle

Tags: polar-coordinates

Question) Find the equation in polar coordinates of the circle with center at the point (1,0) and which passes through the origin.

What I did first was write the equation as (x+1)^2 + (y)^2 = r^2 and since the circle passes through the origin, I substituted x and y as 0 and ended up getting the value of the radius as 1. I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: polar coordinates describe curves in terms of radial distance and an angle between 0 and $2\pi$. Would a circle need both of these?

Comment: $r=2\cos(\theta)$

Comment: First of all, if your circle is centered at $(1,0)$, shouldn't it be $(x-1)^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**
So now your circle has the equation $$(x+1)^2 + y^2 = 1.$$

You can expand $(x+1)^2$ and note that $x^2+y^2 = r^2$ while $x = r\cos \theta$. What do you get?